# Custom controller SDL DXA (Bad Request) JAVA DXA 1.5 exception

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.5

Using the reference of campaign custom controller from the reference document i created my own custom controller. Following entries were made

URL When the controller should be invoked:

http://localhost:9081/dev/sr?query=insurance

Initializer:

```
@RegisteredViewModel(viewName = "SearchResults", modelClass = SearchModel.class, controllerName = "Search")
```

})

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(ControllerUtils.INCLUDE_PATH_PREFIX + "Training/Search")
public class SearchController extends EntityController {
@Autowired
```

View File Name :  SearchResults.jsp

SDL Config:

[image]

Exception Details:

> [5/17/17 10:17:12:458 EDT] 00000116 SystemOut     O 10:17:12.458 [WebContainer : 3] DEBUG c.s.w.c.impl.taglib.dxa.RegionTag - Including region: MainBody
>   [5/17/17 10:17:12:460 EDT] 00000116 SystemOut     O 10:17:12.459 [WebContainer : 3] TRACE c.s.w.c.i.i.StaticContentInterceptor - preHandle: /dev/sr
>   [5/17/17 10:17:12:460 EDT] 00000116 SystemOut     O 10:17:12.460 [WebContainer : 3] TRACE c.s.w.c.controller.RegionController - handleGetRegion: regionName=MainBody
>   [5/17/17 10:17:12:460 EDT] 00000116 SystemOut     O 10:17:12.460 [WebContainer : 3] TRACE c.s.w.c.controller.RegionController - Region MvcData: MvcDataImpl(controllerAreaName=Core, controllerName=Region, actionName=Region, areaName=Training, viewName=MainBody, regionAreaName=null, regionName=null, routeValues={}, metadata={})
>   [5/17/17 10:17:12:465 EDT] 00000116 SystemOut     O 10:17:12.465 [WebContainer : 3] TRACE c.s.w.c.i.i.StaticContentInterceptor - preHandle: /dev/sr
>   [5/17/17 10:17:12:471 EDT] 00000116 SystemOut     O 10:17:12.470 [WebContainer : 3] ERROR c.s.w.c.controller.PageController - Exception while processing request for: /system/mvc/Training/SearchController/Entity/187963
>   com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.exception.BadRequestException: Request to unknown action: /system/mvc/Training/SearchController/Entity/187963
>       at com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.PageController.handleGetUnknownAction(PageController.java:258) ~[dxa-common-api-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88) ~[na:1.7.0]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55) ~[na:1.7.0]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618) ~[na:2.6 (01-06-2014)]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219) ~[spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) ~[spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:100) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:604) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:565) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) ~[spring-web

Comment: According to the error message, the Controller's URL is expected to contain `/Training/SearchController` instead of `/Training/Search`.  Frankly, this is not what I would expect, but can you try changing the URL in the `@RequestMapping` ?

Comment: Thanks @Rick. I was able to fix this by replacing all the alias for controller  (Search--> SearchController) in the component template and controller '@RequestMapping' . This is weird as the reference document allows the alias names

Comment: Yeah, as said, it should work without the `Controller` suffix. See, for example, https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/blob/release/1.5/webapp-java/dxa-module-search/src/main/java/com/sdl/dxa/modules/search/controller/SearchController.java